# How to convert a file loop into LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I have a method as following:

```
public static GatewayClient GetCurGwClient(System.Net.IPAddress gwIP)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listKateApiObjcts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listKateApiObjcts[i].CurrentGatewayClient.Gateway.IpAddress.ToString() == 
            gwIP.ToString())
        {
            return listKateApiObjcts[i].CurrentGatewayClient;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I want to use **LINQ** to simplify this piece of code but I couldn't do it properly.

Comment: `return listKateApiObjcts.FirstOrDefault(item => item.CurrentGatewayClient.Gateway.IpAddress.ToString() == gwIP.ToString())?.CurrentGatewayClient;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8):

```
 public static GatewayClient GetCurGwClient(System.Net.IPAddress gwIP) { 
   return listKateApiObjcts
     .Select(item => item.CurrentGatewayClient) 
     .FirstOrDefault(client => client.Gateway.IpAddress.ToString() == gwIP.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: I can't call listKateApiObjects with this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) returns the first element that fulfills a certain condition. If no element is found that fulfills the condition, the default value of the type is returned (null for reference types). Your code would look like this:

```
public static GatewayClient GetCurGwClient(System.Net.IPAddress gwIP)//string
{
    return listKateApiObjcts
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CurrentGatewayClient.Gateway.IpAddress.ToString() == gwIP.ToString())
     ?.CurrentGatewayClient;
}
```